# Possible to create a file in memory?

Tags: c#

What I need to do is create a file in memory, write to that file, and then access that file as  you would with any other file.

Here I am creating and using an actual file:

```
if (!File.Exists(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "TEST.csv")))
{
    File.Create(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "TEST.csv")).Dispose();
    using (TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "TEST.csv")))
    {
        foreach (string[] array in listOfRows)
        {
            string dataString = array[0] + "," + array[1] + "," + array[2] + "," + array[3];
            tw.WriteLine(dataString);
        }
        tw.Close();
    }
}
else if (File.Exists(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "TEST.csv")))
{
    using (TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "TEST.csv")))
    {
        foreach (string[] array in listOfRows)
        {
            string dataString = array[0] + "," + array[1] + "," + array[2] + "," + array[3];
            tw.WriteLine(dataString);
        }
        tw.Close();
    }
}

//makes virtual table to be copied to database
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
string line = null;
int i = 0;
using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "TEST.csv")))
{
    //etc etc etc
}
```

So as you can see, currently I am just creating a file and then writing data to it, and then using that file. It would be much better for me if I could just do all this in virtual memory, is this possible?

Comment: Use a `MemoryStream`?

Comment: Why do you feel it would be much better? Unless a specific performance issue is present, you may be trying to fix a problem that doesn't exist.

Comment: Please take some time to fix up the indentation of your code - it's all over the place at the moment.

Comment: "do all this in virtual memory" - as in "I want to use array instead of an instance of strongly typed class, write it to CSV without proper encoding and than re-read whole file to `DataTable` instead of adding single line to it"? There are better ways for each part... and even than beating files with custom in-memory code requires more effort that most people are willing to put in in.

Answer (score 5):

Well, you could read/write to a byte array using a `MemoryStream`. You don't get "lines" with this approach, but its close.

That being said, it sounds like you are way down the rabbit hole if you are writing and reading a file right away. Files are for *persistence*.

If you just want to store a collection of lines of strings in memory, you want to use a `StringBuilder` or perhaps just a `List<T>`.

Comment: +1 Despite you giving the other answer a +1 for "giving him what he wants, not what he probably needs", and dispite me often being irritated when I get an answer or comment on one of my questions that questions whether I'm sane to be asking for what I'm asking, I think it is very good in this case that you point out that it's unlikely that what he's asking for is what he really needs.

Comment: +1. Note that `MemoryStream` is fine for small amount of data - larger data sets will hit performance issues with the way `MemoryStream` manages memory (copy on grow instead of chunked storage).

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like you want a memory mapped file (.Net 4 or higher needed) From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorymappedfiles.memorymappedfile(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        long offset = 0x10000000; // 256 megabytes 
        long length = 0x20000000; // 512 megabytes 

        // Create the memory-mapped file. 
        using (var mmf = MemoryMappedFile.CreateFromFile(@"c:\ExtremelyLargeImage.data", FileMode.Open,"ImgA"))
        {
            // Create a random access view, from the 256th megabyte (the offset) 
            // to the 768th megabyte (the offset plus length). 
            using (var accessor = mmf.CreateViewAccessor(offset, length))
            {
                int colorSize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(MyColor));
                MyColor color;

                // Make changes to the view. 
                for (long i = 0; i < length; i += colorSize)
                {
                    accessor.Read(i, out color);
                    color.Brighten(10);
                    accessor.Write(i, ref color);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

public struct MyColor
{
    public short Red;
    public short Green;
    public short Blue;
    public short Alpha;

    // Make the view brighter. 
    public void Brighten(short value)
    {
        Red = (short)Math.Min(short.MaxValue, (int)Red + value);
        Green = (short)Math.Min(short.MaxValue, (int)Green + value);
        Blue = (short)Math.Min(short.MaxValue, (int)Blue + value);
        Alpha = (short)Math.Min(short.MaxValue, (int)Alpha + value);
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for doing exactly what he asked.